# How to read a interger with a "," thousand sep in a CSV file

Tags: r, csv

I have a CSV file like this:

```
Year,All,Northeast,Midwest,South,West,     CPI 
1987,"85,600","133,300","66,000","80,400","113,200",113.6
1988,"89,300","143,000","68,400","82,200","124,900",118.3
1989,"89,500","127,700","71,800","84,400","127,100",124
1990,"92,000","126,400","75,300","85,100","129,600",130.7
1991,"97,100","129,100","79,500","88,500","135,300",136.2
1992,"99,700","128,900","83,000","91,500","131,500",140.3
1993,"103,100","129,100","86,000","94,300","132,500",144.5
```

The code is like this:

```
> fn <- paste(data.path, p2, "tmp.csv", sep="//")
> d <- read.csv(fn)
> str(d)
'data.frame':   7 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ Year     : int  1987 1988 1989 1990 1991 1992 1993
 $ All      : Factor w/ 7 levels "103,100","85,600",..: 2 3 4 5 6 7 1
 $ Northeast: Factor w/ 6 levels "126,400","127,700",..: 5 6 2 1 4 3 4
 $ Midwest  : Factor w/ 7 levels "66,000","68,400",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
 $ South    : Factor w/ 7 levels "80,400","82,200",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
 $ West     : Factor w/ 7 levels "113,200","124,900",..: 1 2 3 4 7 5 6
 $ CPI      : num  114 118 124 131 136 ...
> d
  Year     All Northeast Midwest  South    West   CPI
1 1987  85,600   133,300  66,000 80,400 113,200 113.6
2 1988  89,300   143,000  68,400 82,200 124,900 118.3
3 1989  89,500   127,700  71,800 84,400 127,100 124.0
4 1990  92,000   126,400  75,300 85,100 129,600 130.7
5 1991  97,100   129,100  79,500 88,500 135,300 136.2
6 1992  99,700   128,900  83,000 91,500 131,500 140.3
7 1993 103,100   129,100  86,000 94,300 132,500 144.5
```

When I use read.csv function, it takes "All,Northeast,Midwest,South,West" as string. How to correct this in an easy way?

BTW:
This CSV file is generated by Excel. I find that because Excel uses comma as a seprator in CSV file, if a comma should be used in the number as a thousand sep, it will add quotes to the number. Excel can do well with this format. But it add some comfuse to the R.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the exact code you used to read in the CSV?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. `read.csv` reads your data just fine.

Comment: The default separator for `read.csv` is comma: `read.csv(file, header = TRUE, sep = ",", ...)`

Answer (score 2):

```
DF <- read.csv(text = 'Year,All,Northeast,Midwest,South,West,     CPI 
1987,"85,600","133,300","66,000","80,400","113,200",113.6
1988,"89,300","143,000","68,400","82,200","124,900",118.3
1989,"89,500","127,700","71,800","84,400","127,100",124
1990,"92,000","126,400","75,300","85,100","129,600",130.7
1991,"97,100","129,100","79,500","88,500","135,300",136.2
1992,"99,700","128,900","83,000","91,500","131,500",140.3
1993,"103,100","129,100","86,000","94,300","132,500",144.5')

#remove "," and convert
DF[, 2:6] <- lapply(DF[, 2:6], function(x) type.convert(gsub(",", "", x, fixed = TRUE)))

str(DF)
# 'data.frame':  7 obs. of  7 variables:
# $ Year     : int  1987 1988 1989 1990 1991 1992 1993
# $ All      : int  85600 89300 89500 92000 97100 99700 103100
# $ Northeast: int  133300 143000 127700 126400 129100 128900 129100
# $ Midwest  : int  66000 68400 71800 75300 79500 83000 86000
# $ South    : int  80400 82200 84400 85100 88500 91500 94300
# $ West     : int  113200 124900 127100 129600 135300 131500 132500
# $ CPI      : num  114 118 124 131 136 ...
```